# Backup PostgreSQL DB from SSH to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ssh

So there's a database on a dev machine server that I ssh into to write code. I want to copy the database from there to my local machine. But I can't get the following to work. Can you tell me what's wrong and where to go from here? (See image)[image]

Comment: So just ssh into that machine and run pg_dump locally, then copy the files to your computer with scp

Comment: Where would it put that file? Is it this command? 

Backup: $ pg_dump -U {user-name} {source_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following to transfer it across with pg_dump:

```
ssh blau08@blau08 'pg_dump -C fieldfacts' | psql template1
```

This way you run `pg_dump` on the remote server, and direct the output to your locally-running psql. This system is effective for large databases, since it doesn't create any intermediate files, and is (relatively) fast and secure. If the database is large, compressing the output and using aes128-gcm@openssh.com may improve performance (`ssh -C -c aes128-gcm@openssh.com ...`)